# Xampp .HTAccess maximum caching / GZIP / speed

Tags: .htaccess, caching, xampp, gzip

I'm trying to achieve the best caching/ gzip/ speed with my .htaccess so far I have nothing, can some one help me achieve this?

Comment: Some .htaccess examples but they brake my site

Answer (score 0):

GZip and caching don't really work together if you are serving all your resources from a single Apache server (or any server as far as I can tell).  It's complicated, but you can read about it here:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39727

Skip to Roy Fielding's synopsis of the futility of this approach here:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39727#c31

Basically, you undermine some of HTTP's verbs (PUT and conditional GETs) in such a way that it becomes very difficult to manage when you're dealing with a chain of servers.

The short story is, just enable client-side caching for the biggest single performance boost.  If you can serve different files from different servers (e.g. staticfiles.mydomain.com and dynamicfiles.mydomain.com) then you can enable GZip on the dynamic content if you are NOT caching it.

Here is a basic setup for static file caching in .htaccess (*RECOMMENDED*):

```
# Apache Cache Setting
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/html "modification plus 1 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "modification plus 1 days"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "modification plus 1 days"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "modification plus 1 days" 
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 years"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 years"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 years"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 years"
    EXpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 years"
    ExpiresByType video/x-flv "access plus 1 years"
</IfModule>
```

In case you don't care about the arguments above, there is a work-around 
if you really want to enable both caching and GZip (but it is *NOT* recommended):

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 

<IfModule mod_deflate.so>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hours"
ExpiresByType text/html "modification plus 1 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "modification plus 1 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "modification plus 1 days"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "modification plus 1 days" 
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 years"
EXpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType video/x-flv "access plus 1 years"
</IfModule>

# remove the ETag (which circumvents the problem but invalidates
# an important part of the caching (i.e. uniqueness).  
# This is not a good thing!!
FileETag None
```

Good luck! :)